# How to make grunt watch and grunt nodemon work together

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I have a web app in node.js that I want to start with nodemon, so everytime the main script changes, the webapp can start again.
At the same time, I have my coffeescript files that I need to recompile everytime any of them changes.
I've set up a grunt-contrib-watch task to listen just for `app/frontend/*.coffee` files, to dispatch the coffee parser.
However, this doesn't seem to be hapenning, since the nodemon task is also listening.
I set up `app/frontend/` folder in nodemon ignore.
I also set up nodemon and watch as concurrent.
Still, everytime I edit a coffee script, the coffee task is not bein executed.

This is my Gruntfile

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    concurrent: {
        dev: [
            'nodemon',
            'watch'
        ],
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
    },
    coffee: {
      compile: {
        files: {
          'app/public/app.js': ['app/frontend/*.coffee']
        }
      }
    },
    nodemon: {
      dev: {
        script: 'app/index.js',
        options: {
          ignore: ['app/frontend/**', 'app/public/**']
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      scripts: {
        files: 'app/frontend/*.coffee',
        tasks: ['coffee'],
        options: {
          spawn: false
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-nodemon');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee', 'nodemon', 'watch']);

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Gruntfile instructs Grunt to run `nodemon` and `watch` sequentially as the default task (and thus `watch` is never run as `nodemon` never finishes).

You need to explicitly include the `concurrent` task in the last line:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['coffee', 'concurrent']);
```